# What happens to the degree of the quotient polynomial if the divison is not clear?

Tags: polynomials, roots, finite-fields, interpolation

Let's say that I have one polynomial $a(x)$ of degree $n$ with coefficients over $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a finite field of size $p$.

Asuming that $(x - r) \mid a(x)$ (i.e., that $r \in \mathbb{F}_p$ is a root of $a(x)$) then we have that the **quotient** polynomial: $$q(x) := \frac{a(x)}{x-r}$$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$.

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{F}_p$ of size "much bigger" than n (for instance, imagine that $|S| = 2n$) that does not includes the root $r$. What can we say about the degree of the interpolation of $q(x)$ over $S \subseteq \mathbb{F}_p$ when $(x-r) \nmid a(x)$?

Clearly, $q(x)$ is not a polynomial but a rational function. However, there is nothing that does not allow me to evaluate $q(x)$ over $S$ and then interpolate the resulting evaluations over $S$. At this point, we can say that the resulting interpolation is a polynomial of degree lower than $|S|$.

Can we say better than this? What can we say about the degree of the interpolation compared to the degree of $a(x)$? Is the degree of the interpolation necessarily higher than $n$?

Intuitively, the interpolation has to have a degree bigger than $n$; since otherwise the division would be clear.

Comment: From $a(x)=(x-r)b(x)+c$ it follows that $q(x)=b(x)+\frac c{x-r}$, so the problem reduces to the behavior of  interpolation degrees for $\frac 1x=x^{p-2}$.

Comment: @random Should not it be $q(x) = \frac{a(x)}{x-r} + \frac{c}{x-r}$??

Comment: The second equation is just the first equation with every term divided by $x-r$.